# inter-process synchronization of output to stdout/cout/etc

Tags: c++, unix, synchronization, posix

Is there a way to synchronize output to standard output streams (be it C's `stdout` or C++'s `std::cout`) between unrelated processes so that the output of unrelated processes does not get interspersed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by unrelated.  The processes can be unrelated in the sense that there is no parent/child relationship but they still have to be programmed to cooperate in some way, be that a semaphore, mutex, file lock, or whatever.  There is no secret system call (that I am aware of) that will automatically synchronise two separate streams from two separate processes.

Answer (score 2):

Although there is a function named `sync_with_stdio`, this does not do what you're thinking.

You will need to use some OS-provided synchronization primitives like `boost::scoped_lock` with `boost::mutex` (within one process) or the Boost.MPI primitives for inter-process synchronization.